# How to remove a particular delimiter from a text file and load as dataframe in pyspark

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a text file which has "|~" as delimiter. How can Iremove it while loading the text file as a dataframe in pyspark?

[image: Sample text file: name|~age|~gender rakhi|~24|~F Sujal|~23|~M]

Comment: you should convert it to csv file and load in pyspark

Comment: Do not post sample as images

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just load it and use `|~` as delimiter?

Like this:

```
df = (
    spark.read
    .option("delimiter", "|~")
    .option("header", True)
    .format("csv")
    .load("file.txt")
     )

df.show()

# output
+-----+---+------+
| name|age|gender|
+-----+---+------+
|rakhi| 24|     M|
|Sujal| 23|     F|
+-----+---+------+
```